# Use EWS API and SQL Server database as data sources

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, exchangewebservices

I am new to EF an am trying to build (what I think) is a rather simple application for my office. I am writing an application to track the projects we bid on. Each biditem will track (through navigation properties) which clients (bidders) we are bidding to (construction industry, so multiple clients per project), and project notes.

I am planning on using EF (with SQL Server) for the bidtracker, but I want to use the EWS Managed API to get/maintain the contact info so that the office only has to maintain one contact list which is available through Outlook.

So, is it possible to have mixed data sources (SQL Server and Exchange server) with Entity Framework? If so, can you point me to a good resource to help me wire it?

Here is a simplified model (the `BidItem` and `Note` will be in SQL Server, the `Contact` will be from Exchange):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF doesn't currently support using one context with part of the model mapped to one database and part of the model mapped to a different database. You could use two contexts, but then you would need to handle the interactions between the different parts of the model manually. Also, you would need to find an EF provider to get the data out of Outlook, and I'm not aware of one existing.

You're best bet is probably either to mirror the data in SQL Server or to handle the Outlook data separately (not using EF) and have your own code to bring the two models together. This may or may not be feasible depending on what you're going to need to do with the data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I will mirror the ews data in my ef model, then write  sync tool to keep the sql server and exchange server in sync.